# How can I pre-authorize authopen?

Tags: macos, authorization

I'm using `authopen` inside one of my programs to modify files owned by root. As can be seen in the screenshot below `authopen` asks for a admin password. What I'd like to achieve is that the dialog shows my app's name and then passes the authorization to `authopen`.

[image: authopen requires that you type your password.]

### Code

Launching `authopen` which returns an authorized file descriptor.

```objc
int pipe[2];

socketpair(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0, pipe);

if (fork() == 0) {      // child
    // close parent's pipe
    close(pipe[0]);
    dup2(pipe[1], STDOUT_FILENO);

    const char *authopenPath = "/usr/libexec/authopen";
    execl(authopenPath,
          authopenPath,
          "-stdoutpipe",
          [self.device.devicePath fileSystemRepresentation],
          NULL);

    NSLog(@"Fatal error, we should never reach %s:%d", __FILE__, __LINE__);
    exit(-1);
} else { // parent
    close(pipe[1]);
}

// get file descriptor through sockets
```

I'd really like *not* to use `AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges` because then I'd have to get more rights than I want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple has added an [option to `authopen`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/authopen.1.html) in OS X 10.9 Mavericks that allows exactly this. Prior this seemed to be impossible.

> #### -extauth
>
> specifies that authopen should read one AuthorizationExternalForm structure from stdin,
>   convert it to an AuthorizationRef, and attempt to use it to authorize the open(2) 
>   operation.
>
> The authorization should refer to the sys.openfile right corresponding to the requested operation.
>
> The authorization data will be read before any additional data supplied on `stdin`, and will
>   not be included in data written with `-w`.

I have not used this yet, so I do not have any sample code. *If someone has, please add it to this answer.*

Comment: Here’s example code https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods-app/blob/3fddc67691d269356440305670fadb4a1790f28b/app/CocoaPods/CLI%20Integrations/CPCLIToolInstallationController.m#L300-L341

Answer (score 0):

I think if you give your app path in the 1st arg:

```
execl(authopenPath,
      "app path", // <--
      "-stdoutpipe",
      [self.device.devicePath fileSystemRepresentation],
      NULL);
```

the dialog will show:

"***`app name`***`requires that you type your password`"

Comment: The last time I tried this it didn't work. Maybe I did something wrong. This has been a known security hole: http://alastairs-place.net/archives/000079.html , maybe it works using the correct path

Answer (score -1):

You need to be looking directly at the security framework, introduced in 10.4, I think, and been the main authorization source since 10.5. OSX still works within PAM (like Linux), but /etc/authorization now supersedes this. Apple does have one or two samples of code on how you could pragmatically create a class/entry for someone to authorize themselves against (or preauthorize/be preauthorized like folks who are allowed to print).

Comment: I'm already looking at the security framework. But how do I pre-authorize authopen?

Answer (score -1):

This question is old but it seems to be possible, as explained in this technical note :
Technical Note TN2095 : Authorization for Everyone
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2095/_index.html

Comment: I've skimmed the article, but it doesn't seem to help with my particular problem. The problem I have is not unsolvable, but it requires a lot of (seemingly) unnecessary code.